# Regex validation input

Tags: javascript, regex

;)
I have problem with Regex, I'm going to create simple validation input allows only charracters: `a-z`, `0-9`, `-`, `_`.
I triend to make it but doesn't work and I feel lost. I was looking for a similary topics but haven't found it.
Can someone help me?

```
  let username = 'user_1'
  let usernameRegex = new RegExp("[a-z][0-9].-._");

  if (usernameRegex.test(userName)) {
    console.log('valid username');
  } else {
    console.log('invalid username');
  }
```

Comment: First of all: Check your browser console.

Comment: And then, go read up on some basics of regular expressions. Right now, you are demanding one character from the character class a-z, then one from 0-9. You are neither allowing them in different orders, or more than one.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the *start* and *end* in the regex string like

```
^[a-z0-9-._]*$
```

```js
let userName = 'user_1'
let usernameRegex = new RegExp("^[a-z0-9-._]*$", "g");

if (usernameRegex.test(userName)) {
  console.log('valid username');
} else {
  console.log('invalid username');
}
```